# Convert model item to derived class

Tags: c#, class, type-conversion

I have two classes and a method. I am attempting to convert a `List<Timelineinfo>` to a `List<Edit>` in the method.

```cs
public class Timelineinfo
    {
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
 public class Edit : Timelineinfo
    {
        public int Confirmed { get; set; }
    }
```

Method:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(SubmitModel model)
        {
            model.Timelineinfos = (Edit)model.Timelineinfos; //Convert the Timelineinfo data into the Edit class,
                                                             // which has an additional Confirmed property.
            model.Confirmed = 0;
            return null;
        }
```

However, on the `model.Confirmed = 0;` line, I am getting an error of:

> SubmitModel' does not contain a definition for 'Confirmed' and no accessible extension method 'Confirmed' accepting a first argument of type 'SubmitModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Submit Model looks like the following:

```cs
 public class SubmitModel
    { 
        [BindProperty]
        public Timelineinfo Timelineinfos { get; set; }       
    }
```

Comment: You can't convert a base type into a derived type. You have to create a new instance of the derived type, and copy and properties you want to keep.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry @Jamiec I misstyped that I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know that is not possible to do with a simple inline-convert.

You have 2 good choices here:

1. Use AutoMapper, which you can configer for that and the lib will make a one-liner for that case, see here: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html
2. Write a Method, e.g. a constructor in your Edit:

   ```
    public class Edit : Timelineinfo
    {
         public Edit(Timelineinfo info)
         {
            Name = info.Name;
            Age = info.Age;
         }

         public int Confirmed { get; set; }
    }
   ```

With list:

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<SubmitModel> model)
{
            model.Timelineinfos = model.Select(x => new Edit(x.TimelineInfo)).ToList();
            model.Confirmed = 0;
            return null;
}
```

Without List:

```
public ActionResult Edit(SubmitModel model)
{
            model.Timelineinfos = new Edit(model.TimelineInfo);
            model.Confirmed = 0;
            return null;
}
```

Comment: I tried to format the code now 7 times, I have no idea what SO is doing here :D

Comment: Code blocks inside bullet ponts are weird. They need to be _double_ indented

Comment: The problem with this is that the `SubmitModel` itself types `Timelineinfos` as type `Timelineinfo ` so you still wont be able to set `Confirmed` property

Comment: Oh true, he has to change the TimelineInfo in SubmitModel To Edit!